# How do I know if my motherboard or CPU is broken?

Tags: cpu, motherboard

I recently built a PC, and none of the fans turn on with my tower or the CPU cooling but the motherboards lights come on.

I don’t know what’s wrong and I have the CPU plugged in so I don’t really know what’s wrong.

Comment: Please edit your question: What is the exact make and model of your motherboard, CPU and power supply?

Comment: It's impossible to determine if the problem is with the CPU or the motherboard, without another compatible motherboard or CPU, to eliminate one of them.  However, if it's an Intel processor, it's likely the motherboard socket.

Comment: It looks like incompatibility between the CPU and MB. It can depend on the BIOS version. Please post CPU model, MB model and BIOS version.